# Why UIBarButtonItem title font won't set from app wide default font unless removed and replaced?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I set app wide default font using `UILabel` extension.

```
extension UILabel {
    var defaultFontName : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set { self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize)}
     }   
}
```

And set default font in `AppDelegate`.

```
UILabel.appearance().defaultFontName = "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack"
```

All text adopts default font at launch except `UIBarButtonItems` in `UIToolbar`.

If app segues away from view controller with toolbar and returns, bar button fonts are then set to the default.

I read a comment in another SO question that described setting app wide default font, and that some views needed to be removed and replaced to adopt default font. I can no longer find that comment.

Through trial and error, with that comment in mind, I found that if I remove and replace the `barButtonItems` in the toolbar in `viewDidAppear()` the buttons adopt the default font.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let allButtons = toolbar.items
    toolbar.setItems([], animated: false)
    toolbar.setItems(allButtons, animated: true)
}
```

But it does not work if buttons removed and replaced in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidLoad()`. It also does not work if the animation for the removal is set to true.

When resetting the buttons in the toolbar is doesn't matter whether animation is set true or false.

All buttons, labels, `textViews` are created in storyboard and all adopt default font at launch except bar button items, so that is why I'm asking.

Why do the `barButtonItems` behave differently than the other views?

Why does removing and replacing them solve the issue?